# Want to know what visitor has typed in google

Tags: search, search-engine

I would like to know what visitor has typed when he comes to my site by searching in Google.

Also let me know if this is not possible.

Can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: look into google analytics

Comment: How to check in real time though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google stopped some time ago providing search query in their referer uri. They redirect everything via `https://www.google.com/url` that strips the query.

I guess you can't see it in real time, now. You could see those queries after some time in Google Analytics (as Dave Pile suggested) or Google Search Console if you verify your domain.